# c# remove everything in List collection after a particular index

Tags: c#, arrays, list, collections

I want to be able to remove all elements in a `List<string>` after a certain index

```
List<string> s_array= new List<string>();
s_array.Add("a");
s_array.Add("x");
s_array.Add("c");
s_array.Add("y");
s_array.Add("e");
s_array.Add("e");
s_array.RemoveAll(/* what goes here?*/);
```

What can i put in `RemoveAll` to achieve this? for example say i wanted to cut out everything from `c` onwards?

Comment: loop up the key words `Take` or `Skip` and go from there...

Comment: please learn how to format your code correctly for your next question. it makes it extremely hard to read otherwise

Answer (score 1):

You could use the key words `Take` or `Skip` to help - Example:

```
var s_array = new List<string> {"a","x","c","y","e","e" };

var sorted = (from x in s_array orderby x select x);

var first3 = sorted.Take(3);

var last2 = sorted.Take(2).Skip(5);
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what all your parameters are, so it's hard to say what approach will be best.

Using `RemoveAll()`, you could do:

```
s_array.RemoveAll(x => s_array.IndexOf(x) > s_array.IndexOf("c"));
```